# Programador de tareas windows 10 (acceso denegado al ejecutar .bat)

Tags: batch

Tengo un script .bat, simplemente ejecuto un .exe con argumentos:
**@echo off
iperf -s -u -i 1 -f b >> 24htestS.log**

El problema es que al ejecutar el en programador de tareas me sale acceso denegado.
¿Alguna recomendación?

Gracias

Comment: Si ejecutas el batch a mano, ¿funciona perfectamente?

Comment: Si, (ya sea admin o usurio normal) el problema es solo en el programador de tareas

Comment: Te diría de hacer mejor la pregunta en la web superuser.com. Que hay gente con más conocimiento sobre el tema. Aquí somos más de código :P

Comment: Gracias por la info :)